# How acess the Files with terminal?

Tags: pantheon-files, files

Commans like `sudo pantheon-files` don't works. Has a command on terminal to acess the Files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `io.elementary.files`, this will open in the last path you acessed but you can entry a path or run `io.elementary.files --help` to see more options

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to open the files as an administrator, it is simple:
*Right click on Files, new window as administrator.*